# Categories widget show empty?

Tags: categories, widgets, hooks

Is there a way I can display all categories in the categories widget that comes with wordpress. I do not want to have to edit the core files and I want to stay away from rewriting the widget, but if need be I will. Is there anyway to hook into the widget just to get this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by 'display all categories', i thought it does that by default?

Anyways...you can hook into it, using the following filter hooks:

- `widget_categories_args`
- `widget_categories_dropdown_args`

Both hooks pass the query args to get the categories as an array.

The default is `array('orderby' => 'name', 'show_count' => $c, 'hierarchical' => $h)`, wherein `$c` and `$h` are booleans and represent if the user selected 'Show post counts' and 'Show hierarchy' in the widget's options, respectively.

The dropdown version gets another value: `$cat_args['show_option_none'] = __('Select Category');`, setting the label for the 'none selected' state.

You'll can hook the same callback to both filters, so that the result is the same no matter if `Show as dropdown` is selected or not.

BTW: The widgets that come with WP out of the box are defined in `wp-includes/default-widgets.php`, the code in there is quite readable.

Answer (score 2):

simple answer:

```
add_filter( 'widget_categories_args', 'mytheme_widget_cat_args' );
function mytheme_widget_cat_args($cat_args) {
    // the default for "hide_empty" = 1, so
    $cat_args['hide_empty'] = 0;
    // we can override any other defaults here too
    return $cat_args;
}
```